# sed not able to process ~user/.bash_profile

Tags: bash, sed, home-directory

I have a pretty strange problem with `sed`, if I do with this:

```
[root@Camel ~]-> sed -i 's/TLRAGENT_IP=.*/TLRAGENT_IP='"${HOST_IP}"'/' ~user/.bash_profile
```

it's fine.  But if I try the following:

```
[root@Camel ~]-> CONF_FILE="~user/.bash_profile"
[root@Camel ~]-> sed -i 's/TLRAGENT_IP=.*/TLRAGENT_IP='"${HOST_IP}"'/' ${CONF_FILE}
sed: can't read ~user/.bash_profile: No such file or directory
```

also tried to quote the variable:

```
[root@Camel ~]-> sed -i 's/TLRAGENT_IP=.*/TLRAGENT_IP='"${HOST_IP}"'/' "${CONF_FILE}"
sed: can't read ~user/.bash_profile: No such file or directory
```

couldn't figure out where went wrong, please advise.

Shell's version is `3.2.25(1)-release`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from `man bash` `/EXPANSION`

```
EXPANSION
 Expansion is performed on the command line after it has been
 split  into  words.  There are seven kinds of expansion per-
 formed:  brace expansion,  tilde  expansion,  parameter  and
 variable  expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expan-
 sion, word splitting, and pathname expansion.

 The order of expansions is: brace  expansion,  tilde  expan-
 sion,  parameter, variable and arithmetic expansion and com-
 mand substitution (done in a  left-to-right  fashion),  word
 splitting, and pathname expansion.
```

The parameter and variable expansion comes after tilde expansion

To have tilde expansion, this can be done at variable definition

```
CONF_FILE=~user/.bash_profile
```

instead of

```
CONF_FILE="~user/.bash_profile"
```